# How do I use hsla as background-color in CSS?

Tags: css

```
<h1 style="background-color: hsla(302, 59, 65, .6);">
foobar
</h1>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qoayrhem/1/

In the firefox debugger it says this is an invalid rule.

Comment: Not for me. I had to add `%` to 2nd and 3rd numbers for some reason. https://jsfiddle.net/j3kprcbx/

Comment: You're right. I first tried with another value (not your values) and thought it's working... this is why I removed my comment fast!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second and third values should have `%`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsla()#values

```
<h1 style="background-color: hsla(302, 59%, 65%, 0.6);">
foobar
</h1>
```